# PHP and XML UTF-8 got characher codes instead of characters itself

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I'm retreiving some data from Sybase ASE database to build some xml string. When I echo this string it looks okay, but pressing Ctrl+U (that brings you to `view-source` mode) I'm getting something like this:    `node_name="&#x41D;&#x435;&#x433;&#x430;&#x442;&#x438;&#x432;&#x43E;&#x442;&#x441;&#x443;&#x442;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x443;&#x435;&#x442;"`

And after I need to write this string to a file, and I'm getting the same confuse... 
`mb_detect_encoding` says `UTF-8`. How can I fix this and make it displays as normal readable string?

**UPD** I got it. My XML string was created worng, without encoding definition. Adding `encoding=\"utf-8\"` solved problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use html_entity_decode() or htmlspecialchars_decode() to convert this string back to normal.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Thank you. But so far it doesn't seem to bring the string back to normal view. I got the same(